# Bluetooth headphone gets immediately disconnected after connecting to macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a *Encok D02 Pro* headphone. After pairing it with my 13-inch 2020 M1 MacBook Pro (Ventura 13.1), I tried to create a connection, however, almost immediately after connecting to my laptop, it got disconnected. Sometimes the connection remains and I can see the headphone's battery status in the Bluetooth setting too, but the device does not get listed in the audio output device list, hence no sound comes out of the headphones when playing something. But, when I use a 3.5mm cable, my headphone works correctly with my laptop. I also paired my headphone with my android phone and there where no problems there.

I tried the following methods to make it work, but none worked:

1. Upgrading the OS
2. Restarting/Shutting Down the laptop and the headphones
3. Repairing the devices
4. Deleting the `.plist` file
5. Restarting the Bluetooth module

I have no idea on what to do next and I really need to connect my headphones via Bluetooth.